# this as unknown as T

Tags: typescript, oop, generics, types

Is the following true:

> If `T` is a subtype of `this`'s type, and `T` adheres to the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), then `this as unknown as T` is always a safe type assertion.

I'm asking because I'm trying to determine whether this type assertion is a valid escape hatch to the potential problem pointed out by error messages like this one:

```
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'this' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ITree<T>'.ts(2345)
```

Or are there additional/other principles which must be satisfied for this type assertion to be safe?

Comment: A single type can't "adhere to the substitution principle". It has to be a pair of types. If the compiler thinks `this` isn't assignable to `T`, then `this as unknown as T` is only safe to the extent that the compiler is *wrong*, which is suspect. Your error message says that both `this` and `T` are assignable to some constraint `C`, but `this extends C` and `T extends C` doesn't imply that `this extends T` (no more than the fact that both my wallet and my phone fit into my pocket implies that my wallet fits into my phone). Could you provide a [mre] so that we can discuss something concrete?

Comment: The two types are 1. `T`, and 2. the type of this, where `this` can be safely replaced with the object which is of the generic type `T`, since T is a subtype of the type of `this` and conforms to `this`'s type's interface.
I'll try to break this down to a simple example.